# Flexbox space between unknown width colums - leftmost, center and empty div

Tags: html, css

I'm out of ideas. Maybe anybody knows how to solve this?

1. all divs must be equally spaced.
2. div1, div2 unknown width;
3. div2 must be in the center;
4. div3 can be empty or not.

```css
div div {
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between">
  <div class="d1">div1</div>
  <div class="d2">div2</div>
  <div class="d3"></div>
</div>
```

**Problem:**

div2 is *not horizontally centered*

**Comment on accepted answer:**

The only way i managed to solve it was:

```
div2 { width: 200px}
div1, div3 { width: calc((100% - 200px)/2) }
```

Comment: If d3 is empty (which is now the case) and d2 would sit _exactly_ in the center, they would not be evenly spaced anymore..? Should there be space between the divs or might they take up all the space?

Comment: What does "equally spaced" mean? Same width? Uniform gap between?

Comment: @Corrl - if d3 is empty, d2 still must be in the center. That's where I'm having a problem.

Comment: Not your down-voter, but no, it is not possible to see "somewhere" who downvoted. ***All*** votes, whether up or down, are anonymous, by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just give all 3 boxes the same width of 33.33% ( `calc(100% / 3)` ):

```css
.d1,
.d2,
.d3 {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}


/* for demo purpose only */
.d1,
.d2,
.d3 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between"> 
  <div class="d1">div1</div>
  <div class="d2">div2</div>
  <div class="d3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply 100% for the width would work as well

Comment: @Corrl in that case the 3 elements would overflow the viewport as 3x 100% = 300%. Which would cause a bad usability.

Comment: Did you try it in your snippet?

Comment: @Corrl no but I know what it does. it will only work as long as the content is smaller in width. after that the size will be broken.

Comment: The requirements are that the first two columns are variable. This doesn't comply.

Comment: @tacoshy - that's actually a good idea given my specific situation.

Comment: @isherwood where do you see in the requirement that the width must be variable? it is just mentioned that the width is unknown btu all divs must have the same width.

Comment: Nope, in a flexbox element the divs will take up as much space as they can, fitting the parent element. I'd suggest that you try, since it's quite useful and easy without having to calculate. If two divs should have the same size, simply set both to 100%. If one should be twice as wide at the other, set one two 100%, the other to 200%

Comment: I've left a comment above asking for clarification and haven't received any. I suspect that equal widths is not what's desired.

Comment: @Corrl I know what you mean (with exception of inline-flex) However, just type in a long word. on smalls creens such the snipept, the columns will not eb equal anymore as the box wiwllr esize to fit content and adjust the other boxes smaller. By calculating the width you will remain the width and overflow instead.

Comment: @tacoshy overflow: hidden will help with that

Comment: @Corrl it will help an `overflow` but not a resize. In the end you can calc it then which is shorter then to think about all other possibilities and use counter-measures.

Comment: @tacoshy setting a calculated with in a flexbox container won't prevent the children from growing. I suggest again you try it in the snippet